# My server occasionally loses ability to ping (and site goes down)

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, ping

I am running Nginx on Ubuntu (digitalocean) to host a wordpress site. Every now and again the site will completely go down (500 error) and when I ssh into the server (which I can do) to check it out I restart nginx and restart php7.0-fpm and even restart the digitalocean droplet but none of that helps. I have also noticed it seems as if there is no internet (but there must be as ssh works). I checked netstart to look at blocked ports but port 80 is open and listening and 433 and a few others I checked.

I checked the firewall but there seems to be no issues there (although if it was firewall i would expect the problem to be consistent and not intermittent anyway)

error logs are showing nothing except
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

which I've looked for the root cause of and cant find. however I don't understand how this would cause problems intermittently.

also if it was a memory error for some wordpress plugin or such I wouldn't expect it to keep the site down for so long and stop the ability to ping.

Any information?

Comment: What do you mean, “it seems like there is no internet?” Sounds like this is what you need to investigate further.

Comment: What I meant is that's how it appeared to me when debugging. SSH works but pinging doesn't (IP address or domain name) and the site is down so incoming connections also aren't working (apart from SSH ?)

Comment: Do you have fail2ban or csf installed? Sounds like dynamic blocking. Have you tried to connect from a different IP when the problem occurs? Although a 500 error from nginx would indicate it is not down, but instead complaining about a problem.

Comment: I do have fail2ban installed. Should i uninstall to test or look at settings for a certain problem? What do you mean connect from a different iP? do you mean ssh in from a different IP or use the site from a different IP or assign the machine a different IP?

Comment: If you got a 500 error from nginx, then it will log something in the error log. If it came from your application, then you need to debug your application. With regard to network connectivity, you should check that fail2ban has not blocked your IP address. Also, the UK censors its Internet, albeit very lightly, and you should use a VPN which exits in another country to be sure that you are not running into a problem with this.

Comment: It's important to note NO ONE can access the site. not just me.

Comment: the site is -down-